# inserting multiple record using single mysql_query possible or not?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a site in which I have to insert values in different table. so keeping this need in view, is it possible for me that can I use multiple query in single mysql_query in php or not.

for example:

```
mysql_query("insert into tableA (e-mail, name) values ('xxx', 'xxx'); insert into tableB (xxx, xxx, xxx) values ('value1','value2','value3')")
```

I want to run multiple queries in single statement. Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Comment: Have you heard about [Stored Procedure](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html) ??

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. The obsolete `mysql_*` API only allows for one query to be executed at a time. To do this you need to use the `mysqli` API and [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: When does deprecation become obsolescence :-)

Answer (score 0):

A single MySQL "INSERT" statement can support multiple VALUE tuples if they're for the same table.

```
mysql_query("insert into tableA (e-mail, name) values ('xxx', 'xxx'), ('yyy','yyy')")
```

However, what you're trying to do is not possible with the `mysql_*` functions.

Although the `mysqli_*` API allows you to run multiple queries at once, I recommend you AGAINST doing that for at least 2 reasons:

1. It's always a good (actually, *great*) idea to use prepared statements, for security reasons. Prepared statements can be used [with the MySQLi API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) as well as [with PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).
2. As you can see from the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) for `mysqli_multi_query()`, getting errors from that function can be cumbersome. The function, indeed, returns only "false" if the first query fails; to get results for other queries you need to call another function.

In general, why would you need to combine multiple queries together? Eventually, the time you'd save would be minimal.
Instead, if your goal is having more than one query executed together, and having the whole set of queries fail if one fails, you can use transactions (which also can speed up inserts in some cases). Both MySQLi and PDO support transactions: see examples here for PDO http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

PS: in general, it's a good idea to avoid using `mysql_*` functions entirely, as those APIs are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to `PDO`:

With PDO am able to do something like:

```
$sql = "
    insert into tableA (e_mail, name) values (:e_mail, :name); 
    insert into tableB (xxx1, xxx2, xxx3) values (:xxx1, :xxx2, :xxx3)
";
```

Just have the `Query` Prepared first then VOILA!!

OR Using the `Transaction` method:

```
$con->beginTransaction();

 $sql1 = "insert into tableA (e_mail, name) values (:e_mail, :name)"; 
 $sql2 = "insert into tableB (xxx, fff) values (:xxx, :fff)";
 $sql3 = "insert into tableC (qqq, bbb) values (:qqq, :bbb)"; 

$con->commit();
```